Entropy driven production of antimatter at high temperatures
Might be a stupid question:
The condition for spontaneous change under constant pressure is dH - T*dS < 0. If one took a bunch of matter and heated it to a arbitrarily high temperature, would 50% of the matter be converted to antimatter? 50% Antimatter/matter is the entropic optimum, and at sufficient temperature the very unfavorable dH term should become irrelevant. Is this conversion even physically possible trough e.g. quantum tunneling oslt? Not to speak of the practicality.

If you hear matter to a sufficiently high temperature then the thermal photons may have enough energy to produce electron-positron pairs. Those new particles will be 50/50 matter/antimatter, but it will not change the original particles.
Regardless of entropy, conserved quantities are conserved. So if a given transition violates a conservation law then it will not happen, even if it would be extremely favorable in terms of entropy.

Is the conserved quantity the total matter or the "normal matter"?

@EmilioFerraro:  The conserved quantities would be the total baryon number & lepton number of the sample.
